# Is it possible to show numbers under a one-dimension barcode generated by ZXing?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I'm currently using ZXing in my Android app to generate a one-dimension barcode (EAN_13 and CODE_39).
The result is looking good but I'd like to display numbers below the barcode, like that:
[image]

Is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply just add a TextView aligned below|center of the xzing barcode, and put the numbers in there.

If you really care about the specific look (with the numbers aligned slightly inside the barcode) - you could set a white background to the TextView, and use a negative alignment to move it up slightly into the barcode.

Don't know answer if xzing supports what you want.  Good Luck.

Comment: You are correct that you have to write in the numbers yourself.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to know if there was a hidden parameter in ZXing. I'll use a textview then. Thanks guys!

Comment: As stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494709/generate-ean13-barcode-with-zxing-library-which-shows-code-number-below-it-andro, placing a TextView over ImageView is not easy and its size depends on image size. So this is a difficult task.